# Silverlight 4: ExtendedVisualStateManager error when transitioning

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, visualstatemanager

So I have a control with 3 states each state toggles control visibility, and this is animated using FluidLayout.  This works in blend when previewing the transitions, but when I go from the first state to the second state in browser, I get the following error.

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR
>   2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0;
>   .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
>   Timestamp: Fri, 17 Dec 2010 15:40:32
>   UTC
>
> Message: Unhandled Error in
>   Silverlight Application  Code: 4004
>   Category: ManagedRuntimeError
>   Message: System.ArgumentException:
>   Value does not fall within the
>   expected range.    at
>   MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32
>   hr)    at
>   MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_AddValue[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1
>   collection, CValue value)    at
>   MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_AddDependencyObject[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1
>   collection, DependencyObject value)
>   at
>   System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.AddDependencyObject(DependencyObject value)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.AddInternal(UIElement
>   value)    at
>   System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.Add(T
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.ExtendedVisualStateManager.WrapMovingElementsInCanvases(List`1
>   movingElements, Dictionary`2 oldRects,
>   Dictionary`2 newRects)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToStateCore(Control
>   control, FrameworkElement
>   stateGroupsRoot, String stateName,
>   VisualStateGroup group, VisualState
>   state, Boolean useTransitions)    at
>   System.Windows.VisualStateManager.GoToState(Control
>   control, String stateName, Boolean
>   useTransitions)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.VisualStateUtilities.GoToState(FrameworkElement
>   element, String stateName, Boolean
>   useTransitions)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.GoToStateAction.InvokeImpl(FrameworkElement
>   stateTarget)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.GoToStateAction.Invoke(Object
>   parameter)    at
>   System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerAction.CallInvoke(Object
>   parameter)    at
>   System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase.InvokeActions(Object
>   parameter)    at
>   System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTriggerBase.OnEvent(EventArgs
>   eventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTriggerBase.OnEventImpl(Object
>   sender, EventArgs eventArgs)    at
>   I2.Web.Reports.Models.MainModel.Service_GetUserCompleted(Object
>   sender, GetUserCompletedEventArgs e)
>   at
>   I2.Web.Reports.Services.ReportServiceClient.OnGetUserCompleted(Object
>   state)

Anyone else had similar issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, its a unique name thing, I had noticed that I hadn't named the instances that are getting animated.  It seems to be a similar issue to this

[Bing maps silverlight control custom pushpin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423895/bing-maps-silverlight-control-custom-pushpin/2753565#2753565)

**New rule: Name everything in Silverlight.**

It is important to note that the element who's `Visibility` is toggled in my app was actually a named `Border` however it's child `UIElement` must also be named, I'm not sure how far down the rabbit hole this goes...